# Tornado async http client blocks

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

```
theQueue = tornado.queues.Queue()
theQueue.put_nowait('http://www.baidu.com')
theQueue.put_nowait('http://www.google.com')
theQueue.put_nowait('http://cn.bing.com/')

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def Test1():
    def cb(response):
        print str(response)

    while True:
        item = yield theQueue.get()
        print item
        tmp = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(force_instance=True)
        tmp.fetch(item,callback=cb)

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def Test2():
    while True:
        item = yield theQueue.get()
        print item
        tmp = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(force_instance=True)
        response = yield tmp.fetch(item)
        print str(response)

#Test1()
Test2()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

python 2.6  and  tornado 4.2
In the function Test1,it will first prints out 3 items,then prints 3 responses.
But in Test2,it will print item and it's response one by one.

I was confused,why in Test2 isn't asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test2() is asynchronous, but in a different way, the coroutine way.**

Tornado's coroutine suspends when it meets `yield` keyword, waiting for the async process(in your case, requesting webpage via http client) to complete. **tornado will switch to other available coroutines when current coroutine suspends.**

With coroutine, your code looks synchronous, and "runs synchronous"(if there is only one coroutine) too.

You can easily test the ASYNC feature of tornado's coroutine, by using two or more conroutines:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def Test2():
    while True:
        item = yield theQueue.get()
        print 'Test2:', item
        tmp = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(force_instance=True)
        response = yield tmp.fetch(item)
        print 'Test2:', str(response)

# Write another test function called `Test3` and do the exactly same thing with Test2.
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def Test3():
    while True:
        item = yield theQueue.get()
        print 'Test3:', item
        tmp = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(force_instance=True)
        response = yield tmp.fetch(item)
        print 'Test3:', str(response)

Test2()
Test3()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

You will see Test2 and Test3 runs **simultaneously(but not really)** in this example.

**The ability of switching between different routines to perform concurrent operations, that's the meaning of coroutine asynchronous.**

Comment: in my case,theQueue has a large num of item , if i use yield ,i need to create more than one Test2 ???

Comment: @JianNiu Try calling `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(Test2)` multi times, this will spawn multi coroutine in background. related doc: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html#running-in-the-background